# Add unique Output files names with loop in linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have 96 bam files, How do I output the txt file with the unique sample IDs? I am looping through the bam files, but need to assign unique output files. For example: SC845414.txt

```
#Typical Bam Files:
SC845414-CTGATCGT-GCGCATAT_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
SC845425-TGTGACTG-AGCCTATC_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam

#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --mem=110g
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12
#SBATCH --time=10-00:00:00

module load python

DIR=/PATH/*

for d in $DIR; do
    python -m HTSeq.scripts.count -s yes -f bam "$d" /PATH1/gencode.v35.annotation.gtf > /PATH3/HTseq/SC845414.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends highly on what exactly you mean by "sample ID".

Based on your example, if you mean "the part of the filename before the first dash", then you could do this:

```bash
for d in $DIR; do
    id=$(basename "$d" | cut -f 1 -d -)
    python -m HTSeq.scripts.count -s yes -f bam "$d" /PATH1/gencode.v35.annotation.gtf > "/PATH3/HTseq/$id.txt"
done
```

Comment: Why is thre "" around this? "/PATH3/HTseq/$id.txt" and not just "id"?

Comment: You need the `$` to make it a variable, so it needs to be `$id`, not `id`. And it's a good idea to quote anything with a variable in it, for several reasons (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)). Well, unless you're relying on features that don't work in quotes (like your use of `$DIR` where you expect the `*` to be expanded).

Comment: This is what I am getting:

Comment: DIR=/P/A/T/T/SC915966-GCGTCATT-CAGACGTT_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam

Comment: id=$(printf '%s' "$DIR" | cut -f 1 -d -)

Comment: echo "$id" output: /P/A/T

Comment: @Genetics Sorry, I forgot to account for the fact that `$d` would include the directory. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Or `id=${d%%-*}` meaning "$d, with the longest chunk matching `-*` chopped off the end".

Comment: `for anything in $variable` is bad form, btw. If you want to store a list of files in a variable, `dir=( "/path/"* )` and then `for d in "${dir[@]}"; do` is the right way -- works even if your directory name has spaces, and actually stores the individual filenames at assignment time.

Answer (score 0):

same;
but using builtin variable interpolation instead of calling basename and cut

```bash
for d in $DIR; do
    fname=${d##*/}
    python -m HTSeq.scripts.count -s yes -f bam "$d" /PATH1/gencode.v35.annotation.gtf > "/PATH3/HTseq/${fname%%-*}.txt"
done
```

(edited to strip any leading path as well)

unfortunately stripping both the leading and trailing parts of a variable at once is beyond me (at the moment).

seems it should be do-able see:
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/

(no affiliation or endorsement; just first relevant web search)

Comment: Is this `sh` compatible or just bash?

Comment: bash as far as know, tcsh had some other convention I have since forgotten